# need to know the status of rsync on linux machine

Tags: linux, rsync

I am syncing my backup server from production server through rsync but now i want to implement the failure notification. When i trying to get status of rsync command it does not give me status =0 on success. please let me know how i will implement this functionality.

```
    failureMailFlag=0

rsync --timeout=600 -e ssh -avzr --delete $sourcePath/weblayout/ $destination:$destinationPath/weblayout/ --stats -i > $fileCreationPath/$tempfile 2>&1
 rStatus=$?
    if [ $rStatus  == "0" ]
    then
        echo -e "$startdate\t\tweblayout\t\t$starttime\t\t$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %r")\t\tSuccess\t\t" >> $fileCreationPath/RsyncLog.txt

    else
        echo -e "$startdate\t\tweblayout\t\t$starttime\t\t$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %r")\t\tError\t\t">> $fileCreationPath/RsyncLog.txt
        failureMailFlag="1"
        cat $failureMail $tempfile >> $fileCreationPath/finalFailureMail.mai
            wablayout=weblayout
            varFailureMail=${varFailureMail}${wablayout}
fi

if [ $failureMailFlag == "1" ]
    then
    cat $fileCreationPath/*.mail finalFailureMail.mai $fileCreationPath/$varFailureMail $fileCreationPath/$tempfile | mailx -s "Failure Mail notification for RSYNC" $EmailSent
    else
    echo "successfully run"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if [ $rStatus -eq "0" ]
```

== is for strings not ints I think

Comment: rStatus=$? i have observed that on successfull rsync some time rStatus is not equal to '0'

Comment: *"on successfull rsync some time rStatus is not equal to '0'"* .. @user2380093 what was it equal to? Have you compared that value with the list of exit values in "man rsync" to get an idea of why that status was returned?

Answer (score 0):

Use ; instead of 2>&1 like below

```
rsync --timeout=600 -e ssh -avzr --delete $sourcePath/weblayout/ $destination:$destinationPath/weblayout/ --stats -i > $fileCreationPath/$tempfile ; rStatus=$?
```